# How can I avoid the warning message: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, database

The code produces the warning:

> PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference

This code worked with an earlier version of PHP.  I am now using PHP 5. There is no problem with the database.  I understand that I need to change a constant to be a variable, but experimentation has failed to identify the problem.

```
$user = array_shift($db->get("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
username='{$db->prepare(str_ireplace(array('SSS_','SSS_','SSS64_'),'',trim($_REQUEST['username'])))}' AND password='{$db->prepare(trim($_REQUEST['password']))}' 
AND status='active' 
AND role='user' 
AND expiration > '{$db->prepare(date('Y-m-d'))}' 
ORDER BY pkid DESC",false,'pkid'));
```

The code appears to work properly, but produces the warning in error.log.

Comment: What is `$db`? I've never seen a prepared statement like this. It also looks like you are either using a poor hashing algorithm or none for the passwords. Please don't do that, hash your passwords and use a recent function, probably `password_hash`. Additionally it would help the question if you specified what version you were using and what you now are using. PHP 5 is out of date at this point, you should be using 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `$db->get` is returning a value, not a reference, and [`array_shift`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) wants to modify the variable that is passed to it. Changing your code to something like this and the warning will go away:

```
$results = $db->get("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ... ",false,'pkid'));
$user = array_shift($results);
```

Here's a [small demo](https://3v4l.org/Xc7EO) that illustrates the issue.